# Handle NULL when using substring function in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, substring

I have to check the contents of Col1 which has values like `somestring (someotherstring)` against Col2 (the `somestring` part)  and Col3 (the `someotherstring` part). Col2 is always 10 characters long. Col1 has NULL values.

This is what I have right now:

```
select * from MyTable
where
substring(Col1,1,10) != Col2
OR substring(Col1,13,LEN(Col1)-13) != Col3
```

I'm getting the error:

`Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

I'm guessing the null values in Col1 are my problem. I've tried ISNULL and COALESCE but it's still not working. I must be doing something wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think your problem is `LEN(Col1) - 13` return a negative number

Comment: can you show some sample data ??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is `LEN(Col1) - 13` return a negative number

Try using this :

```
select * from MyTable
where
substring(Col1,1,10) != Col2
OR substring(Col1,13,case when LEN(Col1)-13 >= 0 then LEN(Col1)-13 else 0 end) != Col3
```